# MySql Injection where OR is filtered out

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

I am trying to inject OR 1=1 into the query, but the there is a filter that filters out OR and AND. Printing the query shows up as "1=1" instead of "OR 1=1". Is there another approach to doing OR 1=1, or replacing OR with a different operator?

Comment: what's the rest of the query?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL treats `||` as equivalent to `OR`, so you can use `|| 1=1`

Comment: Yes, and there's also a myriad of other tricks to attack an application using SQL Injection. The OP should not think that filtering out `OR` and `||` will keep the application safe. The safe option is not to inject strings into a SQL statement, but to **apply** parameters instead.

Comment: I don't think he's implementing the protection code, he's trying to attack it.